# EasyAdmin 3 как убрать div

Tags: php, twig, symfony5, easyadmin

При сохранении данных в EasyAdmin всё обрамляется в тег div. Например, когда редактируешь пользователя, при сохранении, в базу данных попадает пароль в диве и, соответственно, становится некорректным. Как убрать тег? [image: Пример:]

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой (но не уверен, что правильный способ) - в геттере поля вашей сущности сделать `str_replace(['<div>', '</div>'], '', $this->some_field);`.

Например:

```
public function getField(): ?string
    {
        $this->some_field = str_replace(['<div>', '</div>'], '', $this->some_field);
        return $this->some_field;
    }
```